# Hot to free disk server when full ? (it empties auto after a reboot)

Tags: linux

Every N days, my services stop because server is full (especilally mysql service and so website is down)

```
df
Sys. de fich.        1K-blocs       Occupé Disponible Capacité Monté sur
/dev/md/1             10403064   9875912      2868 100% /
udev                  16421232       240  16420992   1% /dev
/dev/md/2            105366664  17734884  82321576  18% /home
shm                   16421232         0  16421232   0% /dev/shm
```

I clean everuthing I can (tmps files, logs etc...), it is still 100%

After I do a reboot,

```
df
Sys. de fich.        1K-blocs       Occupé Disponible Capacité Monté sur
/dev/md/1             10403064   3185652   6693128  33% /
udev                  16421232       240  16420992   1% /dev
/dev/md/2            105366664  17735408  82321052  18% /home
shm                   16421232         0  16421232   0% /dev/shm
```

Everything is OK

Is there a CRON table I can setup ? or safely move mysql server ? or clean some locked files ?

Comment: Is `/tmp` on root (`df -h /tmp`)?  That's a famous place for uncurated garbage to get dumped, and it can be addressed easily enough.

Comment: It's a 10G partition @MadHatter that's a lot of cruft for /tmp.

Comment: @Iain I'm not sure it counts as a lot, but I agree it's fairly high.  Depends on the (undsiclosed) value of N as to whether it's unreasonably high.  Until the OP finds where these files are, it's basically guesswork.  I totally applaud your prohibition on `kill -9`ing mysqld!

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify what is filling your disks and take appropriate actions to resolve that issue.

Given that you delete log files etc and the problem remains and that rebooting solves the issue my guess would be;

You have a log file that has been deleted but the daemon that is writing to the file doesn't know that so it is continuing to write to the file descriptor (fd).

You should be able to find the file by using

```
lsof +L1
```

When you know the name of the file, you should be able to figure out the relevant daemon.

Once you know the daemon, you should be able to resolve the issue. Normally you would have [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) manage a daemon's log files. It has a number of techniques for signaling a daemon to close/reopen or copy/truncating a log file

Answer (score 0):

Files are not deleted (despite it looks so) if they are used by any active process(es). So try to delete files **and** restart your `mysql` server and web services.

Comment: once raised 100% of disk, I cannot restart mysql any more !

Comment: try to kill it with `pkill -9 -f mysqld` and start again

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO - never kill -9 mysql  No No that's just wrong.

Comment: sorry.. not very familiar with `mysql` but doubt that this may cause any harm if disk is already full